# vtop box breaks line, is there any way to continue the line without line break?

Tags: superscripts, opmac

I tried to make my own text superscript definition with a `\vtop` box but it breaks the line prematurely.

```
\input opmac
\input luafonts

\font\tenrm="DejaVu Serif/R"
\tenrm

\def\superss#1{\vtop{\vskip-13pt \noindent #1}}

A Feldman, Certified Duck Caller and Psychic, will solve all your sad duck problems.
\vskip.3cm


A Feldman, Certified Duck Caller \superss ® and Psychic, 
will solve  all your sad duck problems.


\bye
```

[image]

I think it has something to do with the horizontal list being broken by the `\vtop` box but a `\leavevmode` in the definition `\def\superss#1{\vtop{\vskip-13pt \noindent #1 \leavevmode}}` did not help either. I suspect I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: you started a paragraph inside the box so the box is `\textwidth` wide, why do you need a vbox at all?

Comment: `\def\superss#1{\leavevmode\raise 5pt\hbox{#1}}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that works well.  So to be clear, using the `\vtop` box always starts a paragraph, and there is no way getting around that? Or did I do something to start a paragraph inside the box?

Comment: you started the paragraph with `\noindent` (and if you had not had noindent it would have started with any text passed in as #1. ) It is not the box that starts a paragraph.

Comment: `\def\superss#1{\leavevmode\vtop{\vskip-5pt\hbox{#1}}}` is perhaps closer to your original idea but using `\raise` to raise something is more natural.

Comment: not really related but it seems odd to use a superscript macro with  `®` as that character is already styled to be in superscript position by the font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oddly enough it wasn't raised, at least when I compiled it with a U+00A7 char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a `\vbox` will not break the horizontal list but as you started a paragraph inside the box, it contains lines broken to `\hsize` so it is far too wide

```
Overfull \hbox (186.38274pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--15
```

You want an `\hbox` not a `\vbox` so that it is the natural width of the content.

```
\input opmac
\input luafonts

\font\tenrm="DejaVu Serif/R"
\tenrm

\def\superss#1{\leavevmode\raise 5pt\hbox{#1}}

A Feldman, Certified Duck Caller and Psychic, will solve all your sad duck problems.
\vskip.3cm


A Feldman, Certified Duck Caller \superss ® and Psychic, 
will solve  all your sad duck problems.


\bye
```